# Slow performance of custom component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have created a custom text input component based on Material UI and integrating with Formik:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Field } from 'formik';
    import { TextField, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material';
    
    const CustomTextField = ({ name, label, multiline, rows, readOnly, ...props }) => {
      const theme = createTheme({
        components: {
          MuiOutlinedInput: {
            styleOverrides: {
              root: {
                borderRadius: '8px',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
    
      return (
        <div className="pb-4">
          <Field name={name}>
            {({ field, meta }) => (
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <TextField
                  {...field}
                  {...props}
                  label={label}
                  {...multiline}
                  rows={rows}
                  error={Boolean(meta.touched && meta.error)} // Convert meta.error to boolean
                  helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
                  sx={{
                    width: '100%',
                  }}
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputProps={{
                    readOnly: readOnly,
                  }}
                />
              </ThemeProvider>
            )}
          </Field>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default CustomTextField;
```

It is called many (40+) times from a parent component which is using Formik:

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="createMemberPage px-5 relative">
        <Formik
          enableReinitialize={true}
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={(values, formik) => {
            
            mutate(values, {
              onSuccess: () => {
                setMessage('Member changes saved!');
                setButtonIsClicked(buttonisClicked + 1); //updates Recoil global state, to trigger data-table refetch of data
              },
              onError: (response) => {
                setMessage('Error, member changes not changed!');
                console.log(response);
              },
            });
          }}
        >
          <Form className="formContainer">
            <h1 className="pb-3 text-xl font-semibold">Contact Information</h1>

            <div>
              <CustomTextField name="forename" label="Forename" />
            </div>

            <div>
              <CustomTextField name="surname" label="Surname" />
            </div>


....etc, etc
```

The issue I have is that performance is terrible - there is very noticeable lag when typing in any of these custom input fields.  Using Chrome's highlight when updated feature, I can see that every time I click on, or type a character in, any of these custom components, then all the other instances of the custom component are re-rendering - which I believe is the cause of the issue.

What I can't see is why clicking on or typing in these custom components is causing the other instances of this componenet to re-render?

Comment: You shouldn’t be calling `createTheme` from within CustomTextField. You should move that outside of the component — it can stay in the same file, it just shouldn’t be nested inside the component function. You’re recreating the theme on every render of the component rather than creating the theme once.

Comment: For customizing a single component, you really shouldn’t leverage ThemeProvider at all — just use the sx prop for the border radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance improved to a good-enough level by replacing Formik's Field component with the FastField component:

https://formik.org/docs/api/fastfield

Anyone else with this problem then I'd recommend **not** using Formik if you have that option. It's not being maintained any more and causes as many issues as it resolves.